# Нету файла php в каталоге файлов

Tags: php, openserver

Я использую `openserver`, в самом каталоге файлов есть файл `server.php`, но на самом сайте нету. Кеш обновлять пробовал, как сделать так чтобы был файл?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: php это такой файл, который не виден в браузере........и не должен.......потому что это файл на сервере!

Comment: спасибо,буду знать.